# Why am i getting worse performance using a web worker than using main thread in Angular app?

Tags: angular, web-worker, data-processing

I have an Angular 9 app that relies heavily on data.  We load the data from an Apache Arrow file, which is relatively performant but I wanted to try and increase performance by using web workers to process data.  However, the performance is not better with web workers, it's actually worse.  I"m curious as to why.  I'm probably doing something wrong.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

My implementation:
I have a data service which can enable/disable web workers.  The main method i use is the "getDashboardMetrics".  It returns a promise.  I keep track of my workers calls and store them in a promise map so i can just return a promise from the method.

data.service.ts:

```
export class DataService {
private workerCallId = 0;
private workerPromises = {};
private processor: DataProcessor;
public worker: Worker;
public enableWebWorkers = false;

constructor() {
    if (typeof Worker !== "undefined" && this.enableWebWorkers) {
        this.initializeWorker();
    } else {
        // Web Workers are not supported in this environment or disabled
        this.processor = new DataProcessor();
    }

    (window as any).DataService = this;
}

initializeWorker = () => {
    this.worker = new Worker("./data.worker.ts", { type: "module" });
    this.worker.onmessage = ({ data }) => {
        const decodedResults = JSON.parse(new TextDecoder().decode(data));
        const { callId, results } = decodedResults;
        if (results && this.workerPromises[callId]) {
            this.workerPromises[callId].resolve(results);
            delete this.workerPromises[callId];
        }
    };
};

getUniqueValuesAndHierarchy = async (
    columnNames: string[],
    nonHierarchicalColumnNames: string[]
): Promise<{ uniqueValues: any; hierarchy: any }> => {
    const callId = this.workerCallId++;
    const action = "getUniqueValuesAndHierarchy";
    this.workerPromises[callId] = {};
    return this.worker
        ? new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              this.workerPromises[callId].resolve = resolve;
              this.workerPromises[callId].reject = reject;
              this.worker.postMessage({ callId, columnNames, nonHierarchicalColumnNames, action });
          })
        : this.processor.getUniqueValuesAndHierarchy(columnNames, nonHierarchicalColumnNames);
};

getDashboardMetrics = async (filters: IFilters, groupBy: string[], workflowMode: WorkflowModeType): Promise<{ detailMetrics: any }> => {
    const callId = this.workerCallId++;
    const action = "getDashboardMetrics";
    this.workerPromises[callId] = {};
    if (this.processor && this.processor.getWorkflowMode() !== workflowMode) {
        this.processor.setWorkflowMode(workflowMode);
    }
    return this.worker
        ? new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              this.workerPromises[callId].resolve = resolve;
              this.workerPromises[callId].reject = reject;
              this.worker.postMessage({ callId, filters, groupBy, action });
          })
        : this.processor.getDashboardMetrics(filters, groupBy);
};

getFilteredVisits = async (filters: IFilters) => {
    return this.processor.getFilteredVisits(filters);
};

getGroupedMetrics = async (visits: DemoDataRow[], groupBy: string[]) => {
    return this.processor.getGroupedMetrics(visits, groupBy);
};
```

}

I also have a DataProcessor object which does the data fetching and processing.  This is instantiated from either the data service (in case when web workers are disabled) or from the worker.

data-processor.ts:

```
export class DataProcessor {
private arrowTable: Promise<ArrowTable>;
private workflowMode: WorkflowModeType = "coding";
arrowIndex: string[];
private worker: Worker;

get indexUrl() {
    return this.workflowMode === "cdi" ? "/assets/data/cdi.index.json" : "/assets/data/data.index.json";
}

get arrowUrl() {
    return this.workflowMode === "cdi" ? "/assets/data/cdi.arrow" : "/assets/data/data.arrow";
}

getWorkflowMode() {
    return this.workflowMode;
}

setWorkflowMode(workflow: WorkflowModeType) {
    this.workflowMode = workflow;
    this.getArrowTable(true);
}

getArrowTable = (force = false): Promise<ArrowTable> => {
    if (this.arrowTable && !force) return this.arrowTable;
    const { indexUrl, arrowUrl } = this;
    this.arrowTable = fetch(indexUrl).then((indexResp) => {
        return indexResp.json().then((indexJson) => {
            this.arrowIndex = indexJson;
            return fetch(arrowUrl).then((arrowResp) => {
                return arrowResp.arrayBuffer().then((arrayBuffer) => {
                    return ArrowTable.from([new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)]);
                });
            });
        });
    });
    return this.arrowTable;
};

getFilteredVisits = async (filters: IFilters): Promise<any> => {
    const { regions, facilities, patientTypes, visitTypes, financialClasses, totalCharges, dateRange } = filters;
    const arrowTable = await this.getArrowTable();
    const rv: any[] = [];
    if (!this.arrowTable) return rv;

    if (
        !regions.length &&
        !facilities.length &&
        !patientTypes.length &&
        !visitTypes.length &&
        !financialClasses.length &&
        !totalCharges.length &&
        !dateRange
    ) {
        for (const row of arrowTable) rv.push(row);
        return rv;
    }

    const iin = (colName, array) => {
        const arStr = `[${array.map((item) => item.id).join(",")}]`;
        return `${arStr}.some(x => x === row.${colName})`;
    };
    const between = (colName, min, max) => {
        return `(row.${colName} >= ${min} && row.${colName} <= ${max})`;
    };
    const compareValue = (colName, value) => {
        return `(row.${colName} == ${value})`;
    };

    const predicates: string[] = [];

    // if facilities are filtered, no need to look at regions
    if (filters.facilities.length) predicates.push(iin("Facility", filters.facilities));
    else if (filters.regions.length) predicates.push(iin("Region", filters.regions));

    if (filters.patientTypes.length) predicates.push(iin("PatientType", filters.patientTypes));
    if (filters.visitTypes.length) predicates.push(iin("VisitType", filters.visitTypes));
    if (filters.financialClasses.length) predicates.push(iin("FinancialClass", filters.financialClasses));
    if (filters.totalCharges.length) predicates.push(iin("TotalChargesGroup", filters.totalCharges));
    if (filters.dateRange && this.workflowMode !== "cdi") {
        const { startDate, endDate } = filters.dateRange;
        const startDay: number = startDate ? moment(startDate).diff(moment(Date.now()), "days") * -1 : 1;
        const endDay: number = endDate ? moment(endDate).diff(moment(Date.now()), "days") * -1 : 0;
        predicates.push(between("Day", endDay, startDay));
    }
    if (filters.overdue) predicates.push(compareValue("Overdue", 1));

    if (!predicates.length) return arrowTable;
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-new-func
    const predicate = new Function("row", `return ${predicates.join(" && ")};`);
    for (const row of arrowTable) {
        if (predicate(row)) rv.push(row);
    }

    return rv;
};

groupBy = async (columnNames: string, filters?: IFilters) => {
    const arrowTable = await this.getArrowTable();
    const filteredVisits = filters ? await this.getFilteredVisits(filters) : arrowTable;

    const colNames = (columnNames
        .trim()
        .split(/\s*,\s*/)
        .map((s) => {
            const field = arrowTable.schema.fields.find((f) => f.name === s);
            const isPacked = !!(field?.metadata && field.metadata.get("packed"));
            return {
                name: s,
                isPacked,
                isNumeric: field && !isPacked && (field.type instanceof Int || field.type instanceof Float),
            };
        }) as unknown) as { name: string; isPacked: boolean; isNumeric: boolean }[];

    const dict = {};
    for (const row of filteredVisits) {
        let rdict = dict;
        colNames.forEach((cn) => {
            const val = row.get(cn.name);
            const prop = (rdict[val] = rdict[val] || {});
            prop.count = (prop.count || 0) + 1;
            prop.id = val;
            rdict = prop;
        });
    }
    // unpack names if needed
    if (this.arrowIndex) {
        this.unmapKeys(dict, colNames as { isPacked: boolean }[], this.arrowIndex, 0);
    }
    return dict;
};

groupByWithStatusCoding = async (columnNames: string, filteredVisits: DemoDataRow[]) => {
    const arrowTable = await this.getArrowTable();

    const colNames = (columnNames
        .trim()
        .replace(/,$/, "")
        .split(/\s*,\s*/)
        .map((s) => {
            const field = arrowTable.schema.fields.find((f) => f.name === s);
            const isPacked = !!(field?.metadata && field.metadata.get("packed"));
            return {
                name: s,
                isPacked,
                isNumeric: field && !isPacked && (field.type instanceof Int || field.type instanceof Float),
            };
        }) as unknown) as { name: string; isPacked: boolean; isNumeric: boolean }[];

    const dict = {};
    for (const row of filteredVisits) {
        let rdict = dict;
        colNames.forEach((cn) => {
            const val = row.get(cn.name);
            const status = this.arrowIndex[row.get("Status")];
            const codedDay = row.get("CodedDay");
            const onHoldDay = row.get("PlacedOnHoldDay");
            const overdue = row.get("Overdue");
            const queriesSentToday = row.get("QueriesSentToday");
            const prop = (rdict[val] = rdict[val] || {});
            prop.CodedToday = codedDay === 0 ? (prop.CodedToday || 0) + 1 : prop.CodedToday || 0;
            prop.OnHoldToday = onHoldDay === 0 ? (prop.OnHoldToday || 0) + 1 : prop.OnHoldToday || 0;
            prop.HasQueriesSentToday = queriesSentToday ? (prop.HasQueriesSentToday || 0) + 1 : prop.HasQueriesSentToday;
            prop.Overdue = overdue ? (prop.Overdue || 0) + 1 : prop.Overdue || 0;
            prop.count = (prop.count || 0) + 1;
            prop[status] = (prop[status] || 0) + 1;
            prop[`${status}Overdue`] = overdue ? (prop[`${status}Overdue`] || 0) + 1 : prop[`${status}Overdue`];
            prop.id = val;
            rdict = prop;
        });
    }
    // unpack names if needed
    if (this.arrowIndex) {
        this.unmapKeys(dict, colNames as { isPacked: boolean }[], this.arrowIndex, 0);
    }
    return dict;
};

formatGroupsForCoding(groups: IHierarchicalGroup, groupByNames: string[]) {
    return Object.keys(groups).map((g) => {
        const {
            Coded: coded = 0,
            NotReady: notReady = 0,
            Ready: ready = 0,
            OnHold: onHold = 0,
            NotReadyOverdue: notReadyOverdue = 0,
            ReadyOverdue: readyOverdue = 0,
            OnHoldOverdue: onHoldOverdue = 0,
            CodedOverdue: codedOverdue = 0,
            CodedToday: codedToday = 0,
            OnHoldToday: onHoldToday = 0,
            Overdue: overdue = 0,
            HasQueriesSentToday: hasQueriesSentToday = 0,
            count: total = 0,
            id,
            ...secondGroup
        } = groups[g];
        const colName = groupByNames[0] ? groupByNames[0].replace(/^[A-Z]/, groupByNames[0][0].toLowerCase()) : groupByNames[0];
        return {
            [colName]: colName === "day" ? Number(g) : g,
            id,
            coded,
            codedToday,
            notReady,
            ready,
            onHold,
            onHoldToday,
            overdue,
            hasQueriesSentToday,
            notReadyOverdue,
            readyOverdue,
            onHoldOverdue,
            codedOverdue,
            total,
            subGroup: groupByNames.length > 1 ? this.formatGroupsForCoding(secondGroup as any, groupByNames.slice(1)) : null,
        };
    });
}

groupByWithStatusCdi = async (columnNames: string, filteredVisits: DemoDataRow[]) => {
    const arrowTable = await this.getArrowTable();

    const colNames = (columnNames
        .trim()
        .replace(/,$/, "")
        .split(/\s*,\s*/)
        .map((s) => {
            const field = arrowTable.schema.fields.find((f) => f.name === s);
            const isPacked = !!(field?.metadata && field.metadata.get("packed"));
            return {
                name: s,
                isPacked,
                isNumeric: field && !isPacked && (field.type instanceof Int || field.type instanceof Float),
            };
        }) as unknown) as { name: string; isPacked: boolean; isNumeric: boolean }[];

    const dict = {};
    for (const row of filteredVisits) {
        let rdict = dict;
        colNames.forEach((cn) => {
            const val = row.get(cn.name);
            const status = this.arrowIndex[row.get("Status")];
            const priorityScore = row.get("PriorityScore");
            const dischargeDay = row.get("DischargeDay");
            const cdiQueryDay = row.get("CdiQueryDay");
            const cdiQueryResponseDay = row.get("CdiQueryResponseDay");
            const qualityReviewNeeded = row.get("QualityReviewNeeded");
            const prop = (rdict[val] = rdict[val] || {});
            const isDischargedWithTasks =
                dischargeDay !== null && cdiQueryDay !== null && cdiQueryResponseDay === null && priorityScore >= 80;
            const reviewNeeded = qualityReviewNeeded && priorityScore >= 80;
            prop.count = (prop.count || 0) + 1;
            prop[status] = (prop[status] || 0) + 1;
            prop[`${status}NeedsReview`] = reviewNeeded ? (prop[`${status}NeedsReview`] || 0) + 1 : prop[`${status}NeedsReview`];
            prop.ReviewNeeded = reviewNeeded ? (prop.ReviewNeeded || 0) + 1 : prop.ReviewNeeded;
            prop.IsDischargedWithTasks = isDischargedWithTasks ? (prop.IsDischargedWithTasks || 0) + 1 : prop.IsDischargedWithTasks;
            prop.ReadyPriority = status === "Ready" && priorityScore >= 80 ? (prop.ReadyPriority || 0) + 1 : prop.ReadyPriority || 0;
            prop.id = val;
            rdict = prop;
        });
    }
    // unpack names if needed
    if (this.arrowIndex) {
        this.unmapKeys(dict, colNames as { isPacked: boolean }[], this.arrowIndex, 0);
    }
    return dict;
};

formatGroupsForCdi(groups: IHierarchicalGroup, groupByNames: string[]) {
    return Object.keys(groups).map((g) => {
        const {
            Reviewed: reviewed = 0,
            NotReady: notReady = 0,
            Ready: ready = 0,
            PendingResponse: pendingResponse = 0,
            ReadyPriority: readyPriority = 0,
            IsDischargedWithTasks: isDischargedWithTasks = 0,
            ReviewNeeded: qualityReviewNeeded = 0,
            ReviewedNeedsReview: reviewedNeedsReview = 0,
            NotReadyNeedsReview: notReadyNeedsReview = 0,
            ReadyNeedsReview: readyNeedsReview = 0,
            PendingResponseNeedsReview: pendingResponseNeedsReview = 0,
            count: total = 0,
            id,
            ...secondGroup
        } = groups[g];
        const colName = groupByNames[0] ? groupByNames[0].replace(/^[A-Z]/, groupByNames[0][0].toLowerCase()) : groupByNames[0];
        return {
            [colName]: colName === "day" ? Number(g) : g,
            id,
            reviewed,
            notReady,
            ready,
            pendingResponse,
            readyPriority,
            isDischargedWithTasks,
            qualityReviewNeeded,
            reviewedNeedsReview,
            notReadyNeedsReview,
            readyNeedsReview,
            pendingResponseNeedsReview,
            total,
            subGroup:
                groupByNames.length > 1 ? this.formatGroupsForCdi(secondGroup as IHierarchicalGroup, groupByNames.slice(1)) : null,
        };
    });
}

private unmapKeys(obj: unknown, columnNames: { isPacked: boolean }[], map: string[], level: number) {
    if (!obj) return;
    const cn = columnNames[level];
    Object.keys(obj).forEach((k) => {
        const newK = map[k];
        if (cn.isPacked && !Number.isNaN(+k)) {
            obj[newK] = obj[k];
            delete obj[k];
            if (level < columnNames.length - 1) this.unmapKeys(obj[newK], columnNames, map, level + 1);
        } else if (level < columnNames.length - 1) this.unmapKeys(obj[k], columnNames, map, level + 1);
    });
}

getUniqueValues = async (columnNames: string[]) => {
    const returnValue = {};
    for (const columnName of columnNames) {
        const availableOptions = [];
        for (const value of await this.getDictionary(columnName)) {
            availableOptions.push(value);
        }
        returnValue[columnName] = availableOptions;
    }
    return returnValue;
};

getDictionary = async (columnName: string) => {
    const arrowTable = await this.getArrowTable();
    const column = arrowTable.getColumn(columnName);
    if (!this.arrowIndex) return column.dictionary?.toArray();
    return uniq(column.toArray()).map((n: number) => ({ id: n, name: this.arrowIndex[n] }));
};

getUniqueValuesAndHierarchy = async (columnNames: string[], nonHierarchicalColumnNames: string[]) => {
    return {
        uniqueValues: await this.getUniqueValues([...columnNames, ...nonHierarchicalColumnNames]),
        hierarchy: await this.groupBy(columnNames.join(", ")),
    };
};

getQuickMetrics = (visits: DemoDataRow[]) => {
    const quickMetrics = {
        allAccounts: visits.length,
        coded: 0,
        ready: 0,
        notReady: 0,
        onHold: 0,
        overdueAccounts: 0,
    };
    for (const visit of visits) {
        if (visit.CodedDay !== null) ++quickMetrics.coded;
        else if (visit.PlacedOnHoldDay !== null && visit.CodedDay === null) ++quickMetrics.onHold;
        else if (visit.ReadyToCodeDay === null) ++quickMetrics.notReady;
        else if (visit.ReadyToCodeDay !== null && visit.CodedDay === null) ++quickMetrics.ready;
        if (visit.Day > 5 && visit.CodedDay === null) ++quickMetrics.overdueAccounts;
    }
    return quickMetrics;
};

getGroupedMetrics = async (visits: DemoDataRow[], groupBy: string[]) => {
    const colNames = groupBy.map((g) => (g ? g.replace(/^[a-z]/, g[0].toUpperCase()) : g)).join(",");
    const groups =
        this.workflowMode === "coding"
            ? await this.groupByWithStatusCoding(colNames, visits)
            : await this.groupByWithStatusCdi(colNames, visits);
    const formatted =
        this.workflowMode === "coding" ? this.formatGroupsForCoding(groups, groupBy) : this.formatGroupsForCdi(groups, groupBy);
    return formatted;
};

getDashboardMetrics = async (filters: IFilters, groupBy: string[]) => {
    const visits = await this.getFilteredVisits(filters);
    return {
        detailMetrics: await this.getGroupedMetrics(visits, groupBy),
    };
};
```

}

my worker code, data.worker.ts:

```
import { DataProcessor } from "./data-processor";

const processor = new DataProcessor();

self.onmessage = async ({ data }) => {
    const { filters, groupBy, callId, action, nonHierarchicalColumnNames, columnNames } = data;
    let results;
    if (action === "getDashboardMetrics") {
        results = await processor.getDashboardMetrics(filters, groupBy);
    } else if (action === "getUniqueValuesAndHierarchy") {
        results = await processor.getUniqueValuesAndHierarchy(columnNames, nonHierarchicalColumnNames);
    }
    // Converting to arraybuffer to transfer
    const dataString = JSON.stringify({ results, callId });
    const buffer = new TextEncoder().encode(dataString).buffer;
    self.postMessage(buffer, [buffer]);
};
```

There's a lot of async code, which i think may be the problem.  I use a data transfer object to see if that improved the performance, but not really.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A Web-Worker doesn't make things go *faster* on itself. All it does is it permits doing multiple things in parallel.

If you still have only one task running, then yes, just the initialization of the Worker and the serialization steps will make the whole process take more time than if you kept everything on the same thread to begin with.

You could start winning on perfs by splitting the work into chunks that you would dispatch on several Workers, if the task indeed takes more time than the initialization of these Workers, but beware to not go beyond `navigator.hardwareConcurrency` simultaneous threads (main one included) or you'll start actually slowing down every threads.

---

**But even though the whole process takes more time, remember that at least your UI is not blocked during this time, and that's the main use of Workers.**

---

---

Ps: I wouldn't bet your `JSON.stringify` + transfer + `JSON.parse` is actually faster than the internal cloning algorithm of a string.